# Error al usar 'bundle install'

Tags: ruby, cmd, rubygems, bundler

Voy a usar un Style Guide, en su GitHub (https://github.com/lonelyplanet/rizzo/blob/master/README.md) dice que para instalarlo debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
git clone git@github.com:lonelyplanet/rizzo.git && cd rizzo
cp .ruby-version.example .ruby-version
cp .ruby-gemset.example .ruby-gemset
cd .
bundle install
npm install
grunt setup # sets up jscs & jshint git precommit hook for contributors, and inits the private font submodule
```

Como estoy en Windows, cloné el repositorio correctamente en local, fui a su directorio y los dos archivos .ruby-version.example y .ruby.gemset.example los abrí en un editor de texto y los guardé sin el '.example'

El comando 'cd .' no se lo que hace la verdad, perdonen la ignorancia. Cuando lo ejecute no hace nada.

El error viene cuando ejecuto el siguiente comando después de cd .

Comando **bundle install**:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 12.0.0
Using i18n 0.8.1
Installing json 1.8.6 with native extensions
C:\DevKit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
Using minitest 5.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.5
Using mime-types 2.99.2
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using addressable 2.3.7
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using coderay 1.1.0
Installing debug_inspector 0.0.2 with native extensions
C:\DevKit\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap (0x1330000 <0x26B0000>) in child, Win32 error 0
Using bundler 1.14.6
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using ffi 1.9.6 (x64-mingw32)
Using websocket 1.2.1
Using rubyzip 0.9.9
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using multi_test 0.1.2
Using thor 0.19.4
Using dotenv 1.0.2
Using tilt 2.0.7
Using sexp_processor 4.4.5
Using image-resizer 0.0.1 from https://github.com/lonelyplanet/image-resizer.git (at master@8f239c8)
Installing kgio 2.9.3 with native extensions
Using logstash-event 1.2.02
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using slop 3.6.0
Installing win32console 1.3.2 with native extensions
C:\DevKit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
C:\DevKit\bin\echo.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap (0xCC0000 <0xFA0000>) in child, Win32 error 0
Installing raindrops 0.13.0 with native extensions
Installing redcarpet 3.2.2 with native extensions
C:\DevKit\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap (0x1320000 <0x2640000>) in child, Win32 error 0
C:\DevKit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
Using rspec-core 2.14.8
Using rspec-mocks 2.14.6
Using sass 3.4.23
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170414-4804-1jdlfqt.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean
      0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0xCD0000, BaseAddress 0xD00000, RegionSize 0x1CD000, State 0x2000
C:\DevKit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32
error 0

current directory:
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
0 [main] echo 4564 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to
echo.exe.stackdump
make: *** [generator-x64-mingw32.def] Error 5

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: hiciste lo que te dice al final (gem install json -v '1.8.6') ?

Comment: Aquí puedes encontrar las funciones del comando "cd ." el cual se refiere a una trayectoria relativa al directorio actual.
- https://hablemoslinux.org/2011/12/04/256/

Answer (score 0):

Lo he probado desde OSX y se instala todo correctamente. Use la versión de ruby 2.3.3.

Lo que pude notar es que usas Cygwin para emular bash y observando tu log pude ver el siguiente error.

> C:\DevKit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap,
>   Win32 error 0

Investigando un poco pude encontrar el siguiente post: [Post (inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502999/git-extensions-win32-error-487-couldnt-reserve-space-for-cygwins-heap-win32)

En resumen comentan que Cygwin usa ciertas secciones de memoria y en ocaciones esas secciones se corrompen y de ahí aparece ese error.

Por lo que comentan basta con reiniciar el sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta haciendo

```
gem install json -v '1.8.6'
```

y luego

```
bundle install
```